# send message to application from gcm like parse

Tags: android, parse-platform, google-cloud-messaging

I was using parse before for sending message to my application. now i want to use `gcm` directly. I'm wondering is there any visual interface in `gcm` like parse to send message to clients?

Comment: Nope there isn't. But you can use any restclient to send a gcm message.

Comment: You can use [this](http://apns-gcm.bryantan.info/). You just need add Device Token, Message and Api Key for sending GCM notification.

Comment: here is a great tutorial to implement android push notification using GCM <http://www.androidhive.info/2016/02/android-push-notifications-using-gcm-php-mysql-realtime-chat-app-part-2/> and test your app by using this link: <http://demo.androidhive.info/gcm_chat/push_test.php>

Answer (score 0):

The community has already included push notifications in Parse Dashboard open source project. So, YES. Now you have the same interfaces you had in parse.com to send push notifications. See the link below:
http://blog.parse.com/announcements/push-and-config-come-to-the-parse-dashboard/

You can find also in the link below a complete review of all features that are already available in parse open source project:
http://blog.back4app.com/2016/03/30/parse-open-source-is-moving-fast-but-still-has-some-features-to-be-opened-up-see-which/

Comment: I think you misunderstand I know about parse. i just asked about GCM